# aggregate values in dataframe by partly matching rownames in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm thumbling around with the following problem, but to no evail:

```
d <- data.frame(value = 1:4, row.names = c("abc", "abcd", "ef", "gh"))
     value
abc      1
abcd     2
ef       3
gh       4

l <- nrow(d)
wordmat <- matrix(rep(NA, l^2), l, l, dimnames = list(row.names(d), row.names(d)))
for (i in 1:ncol(wordmat)) {
   rid <- agrep(colnames(wordmat)[i], rownames(wordmat), max = 0)
   d$matchid[i] <- paste(rid, collapse = ";") 
   }

# desired output:
(d_agg <- data.frame(value = c(3, 3, 4), row.names = c("abc;abcd", "ef", "gh")))
         value
abc;abcd     3
ef           3
gh           4
```

is there a function for this?

Comment: What's your matching criterion? For example, if three row names are `abc`, `abd`, `abcd`, are you going to combine them?

Comment: say, all with abc.. but, actually I'd like to be able to customize this like with agrep with the max.distance parameter, or something similar..

Comment: Could you work from adist(rownames(d)). That would give you a distance matrix between all pairs of rownames and you could use that to cluster up to a certain distance. You would need to fiddle with the costs= argument to get what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible solution that you might be able to modify to suit your needs.

Some notes:

- I couldn't figure out how to deal with `rownames()` directly, particularly in the last stage, so this depends on you being happy with copying your row names as a new variable.
- The function below "hard-codes" the variable names, functions, and so on. That is to say, *it is not by any means a generalized function*, but one which might be useful as you look further into this problem.

Here's the function.

```
matches <- function(data, ...) {
  temp = vector("list", nrow(data))
  for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
    temp1 = agrep(data$RowNames[i], data$RowNames, value = TRUE, ...)
    temp[[i]] = data.frame(RowNames = paste(temp1, collapse = "; "),
                           value = sum(data[temp1, "value"]))
  }
  temp = do.call(rbind, temp)
  temp[!duplicated(temp$RowNames), ]
}
```

Note that the function needs a column called `RowNames`, so we'll create that, and then test the function.

```
d <- data.frame(value = 1:4, row.names = c("abc", "abcd", "ef", "gh"))
d$RowNames <- rownames(d)
matches(d)
#    RowNames value
# 1 abc; abcd     3
# 3        ef     3
# 4        gh     4
matches(d, max.distance = 2)
#            RowNames value
# 1         abc; abcd     3
# 3 abc; abcd; ef; gh    10
matches(d, max.distance = 4)
#            RowNames value
# 1 abc; abcd; ef; gh    10
```

Comment: ..@mrdwab - even better!! - actually this is exactly what I had in mind but didn't get around - many thanks! I propose to add `RowNames <- row.names(data)` in the 4th line of your function.. @dcarlson I'll rather check mrdwab's answer 'cause it is more straight forward..

Comment: ..@mrdwab - forget my edit.. in the for loop it's silly. I now see what you meant..

Answer (score 1):

This works for your example but may need tweaking for the real thing:

```
d <- data.frame(value = 1:4, row.names = c("abc", "abcd", "ef", "gh"))
rowclust <- hclust(as.dist(adist(rownames(d))), method="single")
rowgroups <- cutree(rowclust, h=1.5)
rowagg <- aggregate(d, list(rowgroups), sum)
rowname <- unclass(by(rownames(d), rowgroups, paste, collapse=";"))
rownames(rowagg) <- rowname
rowagg
         Group.1 value
abc;abcd       1     3
ef             2     3
gh             3     4
```

Comment: I *think* that `a` in `cutree(a, ...` should be "`rowclust`", right?

Comment: thanks @dcarlson! adist was exactly what i was searching for.. and using a classification for the grouping is slick! ..appeciate it a lot!

Comment: mrdwab is exactly right. cutree(a should be cutree(rowclus . . . .